# How to set overwrite in Azure BlobClient when using BlobUploadOptions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I noticed in the debug trace my current approach is triggering a HEAD on the blob - presumably to check if it already exists. I know it never will, and if it did exist I want to overwrite. I just want a straight PUT to shave a few milliseconds and importantly reduce noise in Application Insights Application map where HTTP 404 errors show up as failures on Azure Blob dependency.

There is no option within [BlobHttpHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobhttpheaders.cachecontrol?view=azure-dotnet), neither can I find any such overwrite option in [BlobUploadOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobuploadoptions.transferoptions?view=azure-dotnet). What am I missing ?

I want to do all the work of setting Content-Type and Tags in a single call. I am aware of the below override, but that would entail subsequent requests to set Content-Type and Tags which I want to avoid.

```cs
UploadAsync(Stream content, bool overwrite = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

SDK Assembly Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0

**My current code:**

```cs
                // blob settings
                var options = new BlobUploadOptions()
                {
                    // set content type
                    HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders()
                    {
                        ContentType = contentType,
                        ContentEncoding = "UTF-8"
                    },
                    // Set blob index tags
                    Tags = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "quoteid", "123" },
                        { "responseId","456" }
                    }
                };

                // upload blob
                var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                using var ms = new MemoryStream(content);
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(
                    ms,
                    options
                    );
```

**Update:**

1. The HEAD is being triggered by BlobBaseClient.Exists
2. Also asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/25972) by someone else

Comment: `There is no option within BlobHttpHeaders, neither can I find any such overwrite option in BlobUploadOptions.` - That's not true. Have you looked at HttpHeaders property here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobuploadoptions?view=azure-dotnet?

Comment: Also, I think the method you are looking for is [`UploadAsync(Stream, BlobUploadOptions, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-uploadasync(system-io-stream-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken))

Comment: @GauravMantri kindly show me your detailed solution. I only see choice of 6 headers here, none of which seem applicable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobhttpheaders?view=azure-dotnet Re method, that is indeed the one I'm using in my sample code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `I only see choice of 6 headers here, none of which seem applicable`. The 6 headers are the only response headers supported by blob storage that can be set by user. You mentioned that you wanted to set Content-Type and Content-Encoding headers and both of them are supported.

Comment: @GauravMantri my question is how to set overwrite=true whilst simultaneously using BlobUploadOptions

Comment: I see. I think you are already using this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-uploadasync(system-io-stream-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken). Based on the documentation, this should overwrite the blob without checking if the blob exists or not. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Yes, many unnecessary BlobBaseClient.Exists in dependencies trace

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [User Gaurav Mantri - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri), use `BlockBlobClient`

**Note:** Partial updates are not supported with [UploadAsync(Stream, BlobUploadOptions, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-specialized-blockblobclient-uploadasync(system-io-stream-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)); the content of the existing blob is overwritten with the content of the new blob. To perform a partial update of the content of a block blob, use the `Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient.StageBlock(System.String,System.IO.Stream,System.Byte[],Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobRequestConditions,System.IProgress{System.Int64},System.Threading.CancellationToken)` and [CommitBlockListAsync(IEnumerable, CommitBlockListOptions, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.commitblocklistasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-specialized-blockblobclient-commitblocklistasync(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-azure-storage-blobs-models-commitblocklistoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) operations.

Reference: [BlockBlobClient.UploadAsync(Stream, BlobUploadOptions, CancellationToken) Method (Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet)